# Do firestore transactions run again when concurrent document creation/deletion?

Tags: firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, nosql

In the documentation it says:

> In the case of a concurrent edit, Cloud Firestore runs the entire transaction again. For example, if a transaction reads documents and another client modifies any of those documents, Cloud Firestore retries the transaction. This feature ensures that the transaction runs on up-to-date and consistent data.

**But does this include documents creation/deletion?**

---

### For example

Imagine this situation where a user can re-create/delete two documents "A" or "B" when pressing the buttons "Action A" or "Action B".

The creation/deletion of both documents happen in parallel.

Both documents are added/removed to/from the same collection.

### Algorithm

(SEE THE IMAGE I HAVE ADDED WHILE READING)

When a document is created/deleted from this collection, a trigger function start executing the following code:

```
  if(docB has been deleted) {
      if(docA exists) {
          // Create a document... other operations
          console.log("HERE")
      }
  }

  /* else if(docA has been created) {
          ...
  } */
```

The problem comes with this situation:

```
 Initial state: (second 0)
           - docA is not created
           - docB is created
 
 Both actions running in parallel:
           -started Action A (second 0)
           -started Action B (second 0)
           -finished Action B -> docB has been deleted (second 1.1)
           -finished Action A -> docA has been created (second 1.11)
```

As you can see this is a concurrency problem caused because of pressing two buttons too fast in the frontend (or network latency, ...).

Can this problem be solved by wrapping the algorithm in a "database transaction"? I mean, will the transaction be re-executed (or something) if the document on whose existence the algorithm depends has been created/deleted before the transaction finishes?

Pd: I have also tried checking all possible states in the onTrigger function... but the problem is that two instances of the same function can be running on parallel...

Any ideas?
Thanks.

### IMAGE OF THE ALGORITHM

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does [Firestore's transaction mechanism] include documents creation/deletion?

Document creation and deletions are modifications of the document, so are included in the guarantee that you quote.

Comment: awesome! Thank you!